# Microsoft Bot Framework. Hide text message from users

Tags: botframework

Faced with a problem when using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I develop a bot that will run on Skype. I need create a hero card with two buttons (Yes/No), and send it to the user.
I have to say, that use Microsoft Bot Framework API and Python (but language doesn't matter, I think).
Use **type** - 'imBack' and **value** - string.
When press the button, the message will appear in chat, with the  **value**.
This is bad for me. I want to hide a message from the user in this case is that it only received my skype bot.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/getting-started/#cards-and-buttons) can be done. But I is not working for me.

> Sending context with actions
>
> It can be useful to send context back to your bot (e.g. a request ID)
>   without showing this information to the user in a message. To do this
>   you can append hidden XML to the visible string shown to the user,
>   which is only seen by your bot.
>
> Visible message <context hiddenId='10'/>

It is written in the documentation.
I would be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use postBack not imBack if you want to hide the message from the end user:

> The differences between postBack() and imBack() actions is subtle. The
>   intention is that imBack() will show the message being sent to the bot
>   in the users feed where postBack() will hide the sent message from the
>   user. Not all channels (like Skype) currently support postBack() so
>   those channels will simply fall back to using imBack(). This generally
>   won’t change how your bot behaves but it does mean that if you’re
>   including data like an order id in your postBack() it may be visible
>   on certain channels when you didn’t expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you Lars for your fast answer.
I have seen this opportunity in the documentation, but I need use skype as main channel to delivery messages and, as far as I know, skype doesn't support  postBack()

Comment: Correct.   This is a known limitation on Skype which they will resolve soon.

Comment: Great! Because this feature is really necessary. I'll wait for the update.
Thx!

Comment: Btw It seams that I found solution relative to my problem. It works for me
"buttons":[ 
               { 
                  "type":"imBack",
                  "title":"Yes",
                  "value":"yes <context offer=\"Some hidden text\"/>"
               }
]`

So I close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip that would have saved me some time. As of today, postBack is supported on skype. There is a difference in the behavior compared to the emulator though.

In the emulator, the object put in the Value property of the card action buttons will come in the message.Value property. In the Skype case, the object will come as a string in the message.Text property.

Although this doesn't help differentiate between whether the user clicks a button or writes some text (as opposed to what happens in the emulator) this is still better than writing hidden xml directly, imo.